# R list/dataframe: removing items

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to remove data from a list in the below data.frame.

I only want on file from each folder, but have two files in the "YELLOW" folder for STATUS and XSTATUS.

How can I remove one of them?

(input and desired output below).

```
input = list(MASTER = structure(list(FileName = c("//RED/MASTER_2201106_224156.csv", 
                                                 "//BLUE/MASTER_2201106_070651.csv", 
                                                 "//GREEN/MASTER_2201106_071227.csv", 
                                                 "//YELLOW/MASTER_2201106_234258.csv", 
                                                 "//BLACK/MASTER_2201106_191014.csv"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"),  STATUS = structure(list(
    FileName = c("//RED/STATUS_RED_2201106_223847.csv", 
                 "//BLUE/STATUS_BLUE_2201106_061303.csv", 
                 "//GREEN/STATUS_GREEN_2201106_062027.csv", 
                 "//YELLOW/STATUS_YELLOW_2201106_225046.csv", 
                 "//YELLOW/STATUS_YELLOW_2201106_003452.csv", 
                 "//BLACK/STATUS_BLACK_2201106_190321.csv"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"), XSTATUS = structure(list(
      FileName = c("//RED/STATUS_FRED_2201106_223847.csv", 
                   "//BLUE/STATUS_XBLUE_2201106_061303.csv", 
                   "//GREEN/STATUS_XGREEN_2201106_062059.csv", 
                   "//YELLOW/STATUS_XYELLOW_2201106_225107.csv", 
                   "//YELLOW/STATUS_XYELLOW_2201106_012223.csv", 
                   "//BLACK/STATUS_XBLACK_2201106_190337.csv"
      )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))

output = 
  list(MASTER = structure(list(FileName = c("//RED/MASTER_2201106_224156.csv", 
                                            "//BLUE/MASTER_2201106_070651.csv", 
                                            "//GREEN/MASTER_2201106_071227.csv", 
                                            "//YELLOW/MASTER_2201106_234258.csv", 
                                            "//BLACK/MASTER_2201106_191014.csv"
  )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), STATUS = structure(list(
      FileName = c("//RED/STATUS_RED_2201106_223847.csv", 
                   "//BLUE/STATUS_BLUE_2201106_061303.csv", 
                   "//GREEN/STATUS_GREEN_2201106_062027.csv", 
                   "//YELLOW/STATUS_YELLOW_2201106_225046.csv", 
                   "//BLACK/STATUS_BLACK_2201106_190321.csv"
      )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), XSTATUS = structure(list(
        FileName = c("//RED/STATUS_FRED_2201106_223847.csv", 
                     "//BLUE/STATUS_XBLUE_2201106_061303.csv", 
                     "//GREEN/STATUS_XGREEN_2201106_062059.csv", 
                     "//YELLOW/STATUS_XYELLOW_2201106_225107.csv", 
                     "//BLACK/STATUS_XBLACK_2201106_190337.csv"
        )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you want to remove a specific "yellow" folder or just removing one of them is enough?

Comment: I’m trying to remove one in each list. Doesn’t matter which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but works.

```
output <- lapply(input, function(x){
  
  tmp <- grep(pattern = "YELLOW",x[,1])
  
  if(length(tmp) > 1){
    
    x <- x[-tmp[1],]
    return(data.frame(FileName = x))
    
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
})

output
```